# Xamarin.Forms в VS Community 2017 ошибки

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Разрабатывал проект и в какой-то момент он перестал компилиться. Так как студия не пишет по-человечески, в чём конкретно по её мнению ошибка, просто откатил назад - удалил добавленные страницы. Но после этого код тем не менее не хочет компилиться, выводит ошибки, которые говорят, что по мнению студии удалённые страницы всё же где-то ещё живы. Поиском пробежался по содержимому проекта - нигде инфы по удалённой странице (активити) не нашёл. Подскажите как приручить этого дикого коня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

vOptions это была активити, которую я удалил. Поиском она не находится нигде. Пересобирал проект, чистил папку bin - бесполезно.

Comment: Такое у Xamarin обычное дело. Лично сталкивался с таким поведением, когда не совпадали версии каких-то пакетов. Бывало так: проект компилируется и запускается, ставишь доп.пакет, он тянет за собой обновление др.пакетов, ставишь обновление и... все приехали, все что раньше работало теперь нифига не компилируется и не запускается из-за длинного списка вот таких вот ошибок.

Comment: А тут ничего нового не ставил . Добавил новый активити, потестил, перестало работать. Удалил все что связано с этим активити - работать не хочет. И в ошибках полный бред. Вывод - переходить в андроид студио и забить на ксамарин

Comment: @Antykus удалите все папки bin и obj.

Comment: @Dev попробую. А вы не в курсе, можно ли научить студию отображать описание ошибки в случае наличия ошибок? Сейчас просто пишет, что есть ошибка

Comment: @Antykus если ошибка в общем проекте, то она обычно отобразиться. Если в платформе, то такое случается(особенно андройд). Смотрите лог устройства. иногда помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что помогло:

```
- перенёс папку проекта из дефолтного расположения в другое место
- кучу раз удалял папки bin и obj (они были в трёх папках: в главной, в андроидовской и в iOS)
- чистил солюшн
- перестраивал солюшн
```

Короче долбился как мог, приговаривая шёпотом древнешумерские заклинания, кажется даже вызвал случайно какого-то демона, но не суть. И в итоге при очередной компиляции, прога на устройстве открылась.

Comment: Ну, чё поздравляю. А у меня года полтора назад  такие приключения отбили всякое желание дальнейшего изучения Xamarin. Может еще раз начать попробовать?

Comment: @Bulson Честно скажу так: я уже раза три сталкивался вот с таким поведением этой системы, много мучился и каждый раз говорил себе, всё, хватит тратить время. Но потом приходило какое-то озарение, что можно ещё что-то попробовать, и в итоге проект оживал и продвигался... до того момента как снова заходил в какой-то тупик. Мне кажется, у Xamarin есть перспектива, к тому же, очень уж греет возможность использовать знания C#. Но переспектива плюнуть и перейти полностью на android studio всё ещё маячит

Comment: Понятно, что с тех пор мало что изменилось. А вы используете Xamarin.Forms или Xamarin.Android ?

Comment: @Bulson Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Кстати есть расширения для VS с помощью которых можно удалять /bin /obj /packages папки прямо из студии. Вот мое для VS macOS: https://github.com/yuv4ik/vsmacdeepclean